# Must use destructuring props assignment in className

Tags: typescript, cypress, eslint-config-airbnb

I've applied ESLint Airbnb standard to my code like:

```
<Button
  ref={anchorRef}
  aria-controls={open ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={handleToggle}
  className={`estimate + ${props.id}`} // for purpose of Cypress
>
```

I think that I do something bad in the line for Cypress, but how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class attribute,

```
className={`estimate + ${props.id}`}
```

will expand to something like

```
<button class="estimate + 42">
```

---

I think you got the string interpolation wrong, try:

```
className={`estimate${props.id}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was also that I two times was trying to get `id`, I was trying `props.id` but also:

```
  const {
    deleteEstimate /* eslint-disable-line no-shadow */,
    downloadReport /* eslint-disable-line no-shadow */,
    setNotification,
    id,
    name,
    tableRow,
  } = props;
```